# Where is the factory reset button on Android 4.0.3?

Tags: settings, factory-reset

I would like to do a factory reset of my Android phone. All guides on the internet I read show a factory reset button under the Privacy tab in Settings. However I don't have this button.

Where is it hidden?

I have Android 4.0.3 on an HTC one phone.

Comment: Check ALL the settings.

Comment: I did this already.

Comment: Did you try googling for "factory reset htc one" then following the instructions on the very first link which turned up?

Answer (score 3):

The actual setting is:

- Settings
- Storage
- Towards the bottom is the factory reset option

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.

1. Go to Settings, and then tap Backup & reset.
2. Tap Reset phone.
3. If you also want to delete media and other data on HTC One, select Erase all data.
4. Tap OK.

[You can check HTC website also](https://support.htc.com/en-uk/005-HTC_One/0A0/030/010)

Comment: The Backup & reset button is not there.

Comment: Then do it like this:  1. TURN OFF THE PHONE.

Press and hold the VOLUME DOWN button, and then press and hold the POWER button.
Wait for the screen with the three Android images to appear, and then release the POWER and VOLUME DOWN buttons.
Press VOLUME DOWN to select FACTORY RESET, and then press the POWER button.

Answer (score 1):

Settings>Accounts>Backup and reset>Factory Data Reset

Answer (score -3):

It's in settings/storage at the bottom.